# Queuing Web request before passing into web service

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, c#-4.0, queue, msmq

i have online Assessment application where large numbers of hits during login's and submission of test, server not able to process all request when CPU usage is 100% and many request all lost, i wanted to queue the all requests and send one by one in some time internal so request should not be lost and process all request in back end of server

Comment: i have using asp.net C#4.0

Comment: Maybe look into using a Messaging Queuing system? That way you would not lose any requests.

Comment: @Fuji Can i send request irrespective of complete execution previous request, in some time internals using Message Queuing System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are processing two very different types of requests - logins and exam results, and you are trying to process them through the same channel.

The two requests have very different characteristics:

- login requests are small
- exam results requests are large
- login requests need to be real time
- exam results requests do not need real time processing
- login requests deal with users and security (from a business perspective)
- exam request deal with questions and answers (from a business perspective)

Logically, they are so different that what you have in your single channel are two different services (even if currently they are tied together). They have almost nothing in common.

I would seriously consider splitting the single channel into two channels and run them ideally on two different servers. Additionally I would add inbound queuing to the exam results channel. This would have many benefits:

1. Login requests would be less likely to timeout as you have removed the possibility that exam results be processed concurrently.
2. Natural throttling of exam results requests (via queue).
3. Decoupling of dependency between the two services.
4. Higher system stability, lower cost of support, lower cost of ownership.

Because your services are so different that will make doing this much easier. You should be able to separate the codebase with little effort. You can use MSMQ (perhaps via WCF netMsmqBinding) to handle the queuing of requests.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks hugh, Some of my host are on IIS 6.0 and will MSMQ will be supported by IIS 6.0?, when gone through search MSMQ is supporting from IIS 7.0 onwards, any possible way where i can implement MSMQ in IIS 6.0?

Comment: Hi Haneep - not sure about IIS6 support. However, I never host msmq in IIS - although it's possible via WAS, I just don't like it as a solution. You could host the msmq service in a windows service, the queue address would remain the same, and it would simplify your wen deployment.